# Compile LiveScript that imports other js files

Tags: javascript, livescript, mithril.js

I'm probably misunderstanding how LiveScript works, but how should I import another js file in an .ls file and make it compile? For instance I'd like to access the DOM document like:

```
el = document.getElementById 'app'
```

and load mithril.js (which is in the same local dir):

```
require! 'mithril.js'
```

But when compiling like:

```
lsc -c file.ls
```

this currently tells me that it can't find 'document' or any other mithril specific variables (such as 'm').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling your files to Javascript and running them in a browser, then you don't need to require Mithril.

Just make sure it's added before your script.

For example:

```
# file.ls
element = document.get-element-by-id 'example'
m.module element app
```

Then run `lsc -c file.ls`

```
// file.js
(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById('example');
  m.module(element, app);
}).call(this);
```

This is now just a regular JS file with some references to Mithril variables. We need to remember that when we link them to our HTML.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mithril/0.1.34/mithril.js'></script>
<script src='file.js'></script>
```

It's important that Mithril **comes first**.

---

If you want to require Mithril, in order to use it outside of the browser, then you'll have to slightly readjust your require statement.

If you look [line 34](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/blob/next/mithril.js#L34) of the Mithril source, you'll see that `m` is just a local function. Then on [line 1066](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/blob/next/mithril.js#L1066) it tries to create a global variable `m`, if `window` exists. It won't do in Node/IO.js so instead it attaches the value to `module.exports`.

This means you'll have to use the value returned by `require`:

```
m = require 'mithril.js'
m.module! # works!
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't find `document`? Are you not running your code in the browser?

`require! 'mithril.js'` compiles to `var mithril = require('mithril.js');`

You want to call mithril `m`, not `mithril`, so do this

`require! mithril: m` or this `m = require 'mithril'`